# check multiple values from a select menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

For a contact form on a website I want to add two select menus. I want to keep the second select menu hidden and to show when one of the values from the first select menu is clicked. I have managed to make it work for one value, but besides 'Rohda Raalte' I want to add another value.

I have tried several options and searched a lot of topics, but non of the answers helped me solve this specific issue. It is probably quite easy, but my jquery knowlegde is not that great.

Thanks in advance!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  var Privileges = jQuery('#locatie');
  var select = this.value;
  Privileges.change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == 'Rohda Raalte') {
        $('.voetballer').show();
    }
    else $('.voetballer').hide();
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: So, only add the second select under the conditions of certain things being selected?

Comment: What do you think `var select = this.value;` is doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check for multiple values, you can store them in an array and check if the selected value is in the array:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  var Privileges = jQuery('#locatie');
  Privileges.change(function () {
    var array = ['Rohda Raalte', 'Another value', 'Yet another value'];
    if (array.indexOf($(this).val()) > -1) {
        $('.voetballer').show();
    }
    else $('.voetballer').hide();
  });
});
</script>
```

This is a better way of handling it than an `or` condition if you want to check for more than two values.

Comment: YESSS! This is the code I was looking for. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
Privileges.change(function() { 
     switch($(this).val(){ 
         case "Rhonda Taalte": 
          $('.voetballer').show(); 
         case "Other Case": 
         $('.voetballer').show(); 
         default: 
          $('.voetballer').hide(); 
         break; 

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly, you could check to see if at least one option is selected by doing something like this:

```
if ($("#locatie option:selected").length == 0){
    $('.voetballer').hide();
}else{
    $('.voetballer').show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Switch for example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var Privileges = $('#locatie');
  Privileges.change(function () {
    switch($(this).val())
    {
        case 'Rohda Raalte':
            //do some action
            break;
        case 'Another Value':
            //do another action
            break;
        default:
            //do default action
            break;
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution should be like this, You need to take the selector with :selected as,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#locatie").change(function () {    
      if ($("#locatie :selected").val() == 'Rohda Raalte') {
         $('.voetballer').show();
      }
      else {
        $('.voetballer').hide();
     }
 });
});
```